# Hardware Recommendations for an Oracle Server production scenario

Tags: oracle

I have to install an Oracle 18c database server, currently I have 4 960 GB solid state hard drives, 32 2.10 ghz Intel Xeon processors, 255 GB of RAM, the database that Mounted on this server is approximately 750 GB in weight and is increased by 350 GB per year and has a concurrency of 500 simultaneous connections, do you consider that this hardware is the one to use to obtain good performance in Oracle or should it be increased?

Comment: This site isn't a great place for hardware recommendations since these questions will generate a lot of opinions and arguments. (By the way, do you mean 32 processors or 32 cores?)

Comment: I understand, amm 32 processors

Comment: With that enormous spend on budget you should be asking your Oracle support manager this question - and as the answer said below we would have way more questions than answers based on the info given.  This is a complex exercise with way too many variables to answer on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, "it depends":

- Is this enough storage capacity to meet your long term needs for data, archived transaction logs, backups, auditing, and whatever else you need to store?
- Do you have an existing production system, and what sort of performance do you get out of it? How does the old hardware and new hardware compare?
- How many transactions does your database process in an hour? Your overall data might only grow by 350GB, but if there are a lot of updates and not just inserts then you you could be archiving that much in log files and backups every day.
- What those 500 concurrent sessions are actually *doing* at any moment will drive the size of your memory and processor requirements, as will the amount of data that you need to cache to support them.
- Do you have any HA requirements, and if so how does that affect the configuration of your storage (i.e. do you lose some percentage of your storage to RAID)?
- Which operating system you choose can also affect how efficiently your hardware performs.

My *personal* preference is to use virtualized servers running Oracle Linux with an SSD SAN , but that might not be right for you. In the end there really isn't enough information in your question to say for sure if the hardware you describe is sufficient for your needs or not.